# Are there downsides to larger watt inverters other than cost?

Tags: inverter

I have an RV and I plan to buy a pure sine wave inverter to convert 12V DC to 120V AC. The larger watt inverters cost more but they give me more flexibility to run more powerful things (although perhaps not very long). However, most of the time, I'll be using low watt things.

Are there any downsides to larger watt inverters other than cost (assuming the two inverters pull the same current at no load for the lights, etc.)?

Comment: They are heavy. And stuff designed for higher loads is usually less efficient when applied to lower ones..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks Euguene. Good point on the weight. I didn't understand your second comment - can you give an example?

Comment: E.g. an inverter that is 80% efficient with a 5A load may only be 65% efficient with a 0.5A load.

Comment: You can ride to your local supermarket by a car for groceries, or you can do it with a helicopter. Both will do the work. And helicopter can do more things then car can. What would be downside of using helicopter apart of it's cost? Right. The efficiency.

Comment: There may be some noisy fans which may (or may not) operate at low current (when not needed).

Comment: You really need to get actual product data and use actual load examples to compare efficiency. You will probably find that your actual use will experience considerably higher efficiency than the off-the-cuff examples offered above.

Comment: Gonna have to stop using the helicopter now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiency. If the inverter operates at no load it still consumes the energy. Larger inverter -> more energy loss, even if efficiency of the inverter is the same. There is a loss in a transitor switching and loss in the magnetics, like transformer, inductor/choke. Transitors need gate driver circuit, when more transistors are paralleled the gate capacitance increases, this charge/discharge energy is wasted. If transformer is involved there is a loss due to magnetization characteristics, more iron, more loss. Same is about ferrite chokes, larger chokes -> more ferrite -> more losses.